# Getting "Uncaught Error:" in my spa app

Tags: angularjs

### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Dapp">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<title>..::D_App:..</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="LoginControl">
 <div id="ngView" ng-view style="padding: 0px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Controllers/Controller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Controllers/LoginControl.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Controller.js:

```
var app=angular.module('Dapp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$rootProvider
.when("/", {templateUrl : "Pages/login.html",controller : "LoginControl"})
.when("/login", {templateUrl : "Pages/login.html" , controller:"LoginControl"})
});
```

### LoginControl.js:

```
app.controller('LoginControl',function($scope){
    alert("HELLO");
});
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=Dapp&p....

Comment: control is not going to LoginControl.js....when i run my app its giving above error

Comment: Try removing `ng-controller="LoginControl"` from `<body>`. The controller should be attached internally by ngRoute.

Comment: No change bro......still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code in your **Controller.js**:

```
var app=angular.module('Dapp',['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$rootProvider
.when("/", {templateUrl : "Pages/login.html",controller : "LoginControl"})
.when("/login", {templateUrl : "Pages/login.html" , controller:"LoginControl"})
});
```

Change *$rootProvider* to *$routeProvider* and it should work